# laravel - pgsql - error de conexion

Tags: laravel, postgresql, godaddy

Tengo este error al iniciar mi web:

> PDOException (7) HELP SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server:
>   Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost"
>   (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not
>   create socket: Address family not supported by protocol

El tema es que antes de este error podía ingresar bien a mi web, pero al llamar al servidor por otras consultas me encontré con ese error.

Modifique `127.0.0.1` por `localhost` y el puerto por `5432` pero no logro resultado.

Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Esta corriendo la aplicación en un docker o maquina virtual (Vagrant) o en local? Usas Xamp o Mamp? ¿Cómo es tu entorno de desarrollo?

Comment: Funcionaba antes, o nunca llegó a funcionar esa conexión? Quizás no tengas instalada o activada la extensión php para postgresql https://help.guebs.eu/how-to-enable-postgresql-extension-for-php/

Answer (score 0):

Si es PostgreSQL la base de datos debes editar postgresql.conf descomentando las siguientes lineas y modificando los parámetros tal y como te muestro a continuación:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 1024
shared_buffers = 1024
```

Tambien debes modificar el archivo pg_hba.conf comentando al final todas las configuraciones de conexión y agregando la siguiente linea:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
# local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
# host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
# host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
# local   replication     all                                     trust
# host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all         all         0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0       md5
```

Reinicia el servidor para que puedas realizar cualquier conexión remota a la base de datos